# Mvvmlight, Xamarin.iOS nested binding in ObservableCollection item

Tags: data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvm-light

I'm building a cross platform solution using Xamarin.iOS and mvvmlight as mvvm framework.

I have run into a problem with nested bindings. I'm trying to accomplish the following windows phone example in Xamarin.iOS:

I have an observable collection of type `NewsItem` called `NewsList` that I bind to the `Listview`

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NewsList}" >
```

This list is initially populated with news items that have empty images. As images are loading each item has its image property updated.

The image property of the `NewsItem` model raises property changed events when set.

And the image source binding is created in the `ListView.ItemTemplate` in xaml:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
...
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
```

This binding works on Windows Phone. Images are updated initially when collection is populated and images are updated when loaded.

However when trying to set this binding in Xamarin.iOS, I experience problems. 
Following the example given of iOS bindings I use the `GetController` function on the `ObservableCollection`:

```cs
newsTableViewController = NewsListHolder.GetController(CreateNewsCell, BindNewsCell);
```

In `BindNewsCell` I try to set the image binding, much like in the windows phone example above. This is however proving difficult:

```cs
private void BindNewsCell(UITableViewCell cell, NewsItem news, NSIndexPath path)
{
    // Reference for UI elements in cell
    var titleLabel = cell.ViewWithTag (100) as UILabel;
    var dateLabel = cell.ViewWithTag (101) as UILabel;
    var imageView = cell.ViewWithTag (102) as UIImageView;

    // Set values in cell
    titleLabel.Text = news.Title;
    dateLabel.Text = news.Date;

    // The line commented out below works in setting the image, but does not update
    // when the image property changes, only when the cells are redrawn. 
    //imageView.Image = ValueConverter.IBitmapToUIImage(news.Image);

    this.SetBinding (
            () => news.Image,
            () => imageView.Image)
            .ConvertSourceToTarget(ValueConverter.IBitmapToUIImage);
}
```

This binding does not work. I also tried using:

```cs
this.SetBinding(
    () => news.Image)
    .WhenSourceChanges(
        () =>
        {
            imageView.Image = ValueConverter.IBitmapToUIImage(news.Image);            
        });
```

without success.

I can do regular binding:

```cs
private Binding<bool, bool> testBinding;

// Set test binding
testBinding = this.SetBinding (
    () => Vm.Test,
    () => TestIndicator.Hidden));
```

works fine.

How do you bind to properties in dynamically created items in a observable collection?

**Edit: I have revised the over-simplified above code samples to include a little more detail on the image conversion.**

**To boil down the question: Using mvvmlight in xamarin.ios, how do i implement data binding on a specific property of an item in an observable list of said items?**

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that `newsitem.Image` is a string, because it comes from a ViewModel, that usually contains no platform specific types. So you are trying to assign a string to an `UIImage`. You need to load the image of this name.

```cs
imageView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle(news.Image);
```

Your image must:

- be stored in `Resources` in your iOS project
- have the build action `BundleResource`
- have the name `xyz.png` if `news.Image` is "xyz" (jpg, bmp, ... are working as well)

Comment: It makes sense that you would assume this. It seems that i was a little too vague when trying to simplify my code. In my particular implementation i use a combination of the framework [Splat](https://github.com/paulcbetts/splat) and a value converter to implement cross platform image loading.

Comment: I edited the code in my question to better reflect the image conversion.